# Coverage.py only shows test files

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

When I run the [coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/index.html) commands, the only results in the report are from the **test** directory. Obviously, the value of the report is from code coverage in the **source** directory. How do I view that result?

I'm using:

`coverage run -m unittest test.tests1.sometestfile1`

and all the imports/functions from the source directory execute and pass, but the report looks like this:

```
$ coverage report                                                                                                  
Name                        Stmts   Miss  Cover
-----------------------------------------------
test/__init__.py                1      0   100%
test/../sometestfile1.py      116     69    41%
test/../sometestfile2.py      116     69    41%
test/../sometestfile3.py      116     69    41%
...
-----------------------------------------------
TOTAL                         373    137    63%
```

I've experimented with adding the source dir to coverage's `--source` and `--include` options, but it didn't resolve the issue.

How can I view the coverage from the actual source files?

Comment: It would be useful to include the actual project structure (and the relevant bits from the project's `setup.py`), as with the available information it wasn't possible for me to reproduce. Also ensure that there isn't unexpected entries in `.coveragerc` at where coverage was executed.

Comment: Definitely knowing more about your structure would help us solve your problem.  Also, you can use `--debug=trace` on your coverage run line, and you will get information about the trace/notrace decisions that coverage is making.

Comment: I have similar problem. inside trace is a section with ref to the actual code files. All are enclosed in `pytest_ignore_collect [hook]` tags. `pytest_collect_file` surrounds the test files. This all used to work for me when I did not have a src directory as a buffer. now that I have added it - I only see coverage on the testing files - not the source files. I am using pytest not unittest.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the `--source=` option for pytest.

you have:
`coverage run -m unittest test.tests1.sometestfile1`
which is showing you only the test files coverage.

You need to ensure that the files from your test/Lib/site-packages are getting coverage. (I'm assuming you're making a package for a user to import and maybe for PyPi to hold).

These are being created by tox in the `.tox/test` subdirectory.

This is why `coverage run -m --source=. unittest test.tests1.sometestfile1` does not work.

You need to use the lib name.

`coverage run -m --source=<module> unittest test.tests1.sometestfile1`

E.g. for my project `pyweaving` which uses this directory structure:

```
pyweaving/
    tests/
    docs/
    src/
        pyweaving/
            __init__.py
            foo.py
            data/
            generators/
                __init__.py
               bar.py

    setup.py (just the stub code)
    setup.cfg
    tox.ini
```

my coverage command line looks like this:

`coverage run -m --source=pyweaving pytest --basetemp="{envtmpdir}" {posargs}`